# Controller for custom update query using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, controller, sql-update, rest

I am trying to make a rating counter on a website. When the like button is clicked, the rating value will be increased by one. I want to do this by using a custom update query. I have no idea how to write the controller class since this doesn't involve a request body. I tried to use patch mapping but obviously it's not right.

```
// model
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "review")
public class Review implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1467739098650796381L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="REVIEWID")
    Integer reviewId;

    @Column(name="SUBJECT")
    String subject;
    
    @Column(name="RECOMMENDATION")
    String recommendation;
    
    @Column(name="RATING", columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
    Integer rating;
    
    @Column(name="TIMESTAMP")
    String time;
}

//Repository
@Repository
public interface ReviewRepository extends JpaRepository<Review, Integer>{
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE review set rating = rating + 1 WHERE reviewid = ?1")
    void addOneRating(Integer reviewId);
}

//Service
public class ReviewService {

    @Autowired
    ReviewRepository reviewRepository;

    public void addRating(Integer id) {
        reviewRepository.addOneRating(id);
    }}

//controller
@RestController
public class ReviewController {
    @PatchMapping("/addRating/{id}")
    public void addRating(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        reviewService.addRating(id);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

u are returning nothing u should redirect to the page again after updating and u can use `@PostMapping` also u should write `@Transactional` top on `ReviewRepository`

```
@RestController
public class ReviewController {
    @PatchMapping("/addRating/{id}")
    public void addRating(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        reviewService.addRating(id);
    }}
```